# Best way to send notification if new message is received while app is killed or in background

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

So, I have a chat app that is using **Firebase Realtime database**. Everything is working as expected, the problem is, whenever the user kills or sends the app to background, new messages received don't send notifications to the user. I've searched StackOverflow for a solution to this problem but I couldn't find a working solution.

My first thought was to create a Service that would check if a new message was received, and if so, send a notification. This is the code I currently have (not finished):

```
class NotificationsService : Service(){

    private lateinit var mHandler: Handler
    private lateinit var mRunnable: Runnable

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        mHandler = Handler()
        mRunnable = Runnable { getNewMessage()
             }
             mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 20000)

        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented")
    }

    private fun getNewMessage(){
        // Random code just to test
        val rand = Random()
        val number = rand.nextInt(100)
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 20000)
    }

}
```

My doubt is, is this the best solution for this problem? Or the most **optimized** in terms of data consuming and power efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to force your app process to stay alive.  Android will kill it when the user isn't using it any more, and your database listeners will stop.  The best chance you have of keeping it alive is establishing a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services), but even that isn't a guarantee, as Android will still kill it if it needs the memory.  You should simply expect that you can't keep your app alive, in order to allow other apps and services to run normally.

What you should be doing instead is also using [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) to deliver messages to your app from a backend you control.  These message will wake the app, if necessary, when Android says it's OK.  You can then present the user a notification if you want, or schedule further background work with [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

If you absolutely can't have a backend for whatever reason, you will have to schedule your app to wake periodically using AlarmManager or WorkManager.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to use Firecase Cloud Messaging ([FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)) with high-priority messages and trigger application when user will receive new message

2) If you really want to use service: I had a lot of situations when I needed "unstoppable" service, so I wrote my library. You can try it here: https://github.com/iardelian/Revive-S